# how to skip verification code for a user in salesforce

Tags: security

I want to skip the verification code for a user

I want the users not to receive the "''You recently logged in to Salesforce from a device we don't recognize.'' How can I do ? I have defined lists of Ip ranges under network access.will this solve my problem

I do not have IP ranges defined in salesforce. How can I skip this step?

Please help!!

Comment: I faced smilar issue lately and I feel setting up IP ranges is the only good way to achieve this. I set a trusted range for a specific profile and that solved the verification issue.

Comment: Hi Kunal, this appears to be an [x-y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking how to skip the verification code (which you can't directly do), try asking us how to get your user logged in, what challenges you're facing, why you don't want to/can't use a verification code, etc.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox: I want the users not to receive the "''You recently logged in to Salesforce from a device we don't recognize.'' How can I do ? I have defined lists of Ip ranges under network access.will this solve my problem

Answer (score 6):

It's a bit of a broad stroke, but you can use Trusted IP ranges if the user is coming into Salesforce from a known static IP address. I say broad here as it won't be specific to that user. It will include any other users logging in from those IP addresses. See [Set Trusted IP Ranges for Your Organization](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_networkaccess.htm&language=en_US)

A variation on Trusted IP ranges is to [Restrict the Login IP Addresses for the Profile](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=login_ip_ranges.htm&language=en_US). This will remove the need for the verification code, but will also lock that Profile to a range of IP addresses.

Another option I can think of would be to utilise the the security token. Calls to the APIs, say the Partner API login() method, that include the security token appended to the password don't need to go through the verification check. You could establish the valid session using the API call and then bounce the user directly into the Web UI through the [frontdoor](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000193348&language=en_US).

I haven't tried it, but you might be able to use SAML Single Sign-On to bypass the verification step.
**EDIT:** [SAML SSO bypasses device activation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000232188&type=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) ([via Gorav](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/116835/how-to-skip-verification-code-for-a-user-in-salesforce/116838?noredirect=1#comment359447_116838))

You would need to figure out if the effort of any of these approaches is worth it versus just doing the verification process when you switch to a new device.

Comment: Plus, SAML takes just minutes to set up (assuming the pre-reqs are already there), users don't have to remember a second login, and in many cases, they can actually be logged in automatically by their browser just based on their network credentials without any interaction on their part.

Comment: For the record, this article confirms that saml bypasses identity verification https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000232188&type=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Answer (score 2):

yes ,you can skip the verfication code by putting the  Ip Ranges in Network access in the salesforce org.

0.0.0.0   -  255.255.255.255

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I don't think this works anymore. Not on my orgs!

Comment: This doesn't work any longer, there are limitations to the size of the ip addresses. As a general rule of thumb, I advise only using specific ip addresses and having your users specify the addresses for the locations they're in. Having a broad IP address range isn't safe.

Answer (score 0):

if you are asking about `Enable the SMS method of identity confirmation` in `Setup - Security Controls - Session Settings - Identity Confirmation` - it has the following helptip:

> To disable SMS as a method of confirmation, contact Salesforce support. The email method of identity confirmation can't be disabled.